# Using a leds driver ic with arduino

Tags: led-matrix

I have an ic (CT1642 1442) it's a led driver 8 bit, i want to use it with my arduino nano and i don't have any idea how to use it.
If someone can help me ill be thankfull.

Comment: https://github.com/arkroan/CT1642, https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/how-to-use-an-ct1642-or-sm1642-led-driver-with-key-scan-arduino-project.116955/, https://arduino-projects-free.blogspot.com/2020/07/fd1642-ct1642-sm1642-et6227.html, etc. You'll likely need to be a bit more specific with what exactly you're working with (bare chip? Board with that chip?) and what you want to do with it.

Comment: Start by getting the datasheet for the ic and read through it.

Comment: @lurker No, start by learning to read Chinese - *then* get the datasheet and read it...